# DirectX11 Video Memory exceeded

Tags: c++, memory, directx-11, direct3d

I have a render loop that listens for pen tablet input and draws from vertex/index buffers (among other things). The vertex data can grow and when it hits certain levels,  DispatchMsg(&msg) encounters this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5DDBDEF0 (msvcr110d.dll) in App.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

The total size of the allocated vertex and index buffers in the scene are around the same levels each time:

```
Total Vertices count: 10391370
Total Indices count: 41565480
Total Vertices size: 249392880 (bytes)
Total Indices size: 997571520 (bytes)
```

and in another sampling:

```
Total Vertices count: 9969300
Total Indices count: 39877200
Total Vert size: 239263200
Total Indices size: 957052800
```

The vertex and index buffers are both D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT. The total size allocation in the scene is higher than listed above, but the smaller buffers are frequently released. There is also some padding in the vertex/index buffers at the end.

The message about to be dispatched every time (when the exception is reached) is 581, which I believe may be:

```
#define WM_POINTERUPDATE                0x0245
```

I really don't mind the scene rendering slowly, but if I am reaching some maximum memory allocation (video memory?) is there a way for the memory to slowly page to/from maim memory at the cost of speed? I tried disabling the draw() call which invokes the pixel, vertex shaders, and drawing calls but the exception still occurs. I would prefer a speed tradeoff or workaround to an exception.

Comment: How many verticies are you drawing? That seems like a lot of data. 10 million verts?

Comment: Correct, it seems high, so I'm expecting problems at some point, just want to figure out the reason or what can be done about it.

Comment: That's a lot of verts. I'm surprised you could allocate that many without something catching fire. Are you creating too many, like leaking them somehow?

Comment: Yes, there are some duplicates and some are interpolated, so I've been working on a few algorithms to remove these, but any workaround can be a time investment. The scene is very responsive (more than I need) and there's a lot of detail but I don't want to give up unless I hit a hard limit (or went past one). I'll deallocate and reallocate chunks within each frame eventually, but that would be very slow probably.

Comment: The amount of memory that your indices take up seems rather high (24 bytes per index; it should be 4 bytes). Are you sure you're not allocating vastly too much memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the numbers in your question, it seems that you're allocating lots of memory for your vertex and index data (about 1.2GB). If your app is 32-bit (x86, as opposed to x64), it only has access to 2GB of memory, so it might very well be that your process is out of memory.

The GPU has access to part of the system memory (which is quite slow compared to the GPU memory, but better than no memory at all). For NVidia GPUs, for example, the NVidia Control Panel shows it under "System Information" > "Shared system memory"; this is usually half the total amount of RAM in your system. As far as I'm aware, this system memory takes up part of your process' address space.

If your "pretty old" GPU has 512MB of memory, it would need about 768MB of additional system memory in order to satisfy your memory requests. This leaves 1.2GB for your application. I guess that your application tries to allocate 1.2GB of system memory in arrays that will take your geometry data that you want to upload to the GPU. This would just fit, but your application code needs to be somewhere, too. In this hypothetical case, you've already run out of memory. Of course, you can get rid of the system memory arrays once you've uploaded the geometry data to the GPU, but at precisely this moment, the system doesn't have enough memory to create a GPU memory buffer of the size that you requested.

Switching the project to be 64-bit (x64 in Visual Studio) would enable your process to take up vastly more memory (in most cases up to what's available in your system and the pagefile), and resolve your problem. If memory constraints are actually the problem.

Another thing: I noticed that - assuming your numbers are right - you allocate 24 bytes per index for the index buffer, just as much as you allocate for each vertex in the vertex buffer. Is that correct? An index (which is just an offset into the vertex buffer) should not be larger than 4 bytes. Do you really try to allocate 6 times as much GPU memory as you actually need, or is it a mis-calculation in your application?

If you quickly release and then re-create a buffer on the GPU, then D3D might keep the "old" buffer around for a while (at least as long as it's still bound to the GPU pipeline), so it might be out of memory because of that. So it might help to actually unbind the buffers that you're about to release (by calling `IASetVertexBuffers(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0)` and `IASetIndexBuffer(NULL, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)`).

Comment: The indices allocations may have been off, but each vertex was being re-used quite a bit to build a pyramid or diamond type of shape. This is being replaced by control points and tessellation or geometry shaders for realtime rendering and spheres for offline rendering. The 32-bit address space is a huge problem, thank you for mentioning this, I completely overlooked that. I'm using some 32-bit libraries I built and will need to port those. Also using a W5100 Firepro now, which will expand the memory capabilities as well.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not the number of indices that seems too high (reusing indices FTW), but the amount of memory (number of bytes) that your indices take up. The 41565480 indices in your first example should take up 41565480 * 4 = 166261920 bytes (166MB), but according to your question, 997571520 bytes (997MB!) are allocated, pushing memory usage almost definitely past the memory restrictions of a 32-bit process. Since the amount of memory stated is the number of indices multiplied by 24 (which is your vertex size), it could be an error in your index buffer size calculation or just a typo.

Comment: I think so! Had this commented out, but not sure which debug messages I was using //debugMsg("Ind size: " + iToS(sizeof(Vertex)*editingModel->builtIndicesCount)); So it was allocating less, just displaying incorrectly in my debug log. Already using Control Points and changing the way the geometry is built, but good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer and resolved the problem. Depending on my input vertices counts, a CreateBuffer was failing or a malloc/HeapAlloc was failing.

I'm still not 100% certain if the GPU should be paging memory to main system memory after a certain point, or if this is unavoidable since the scene data must remain on GPU memory during each frame's computations (depth, lighting, etc), but I think A) paging would only be possible if I manually dealloc'ed/realloc'ed the buffers (would be slow anyway) and B) the size of alloc'ed buffers (vertices,indices..) is the problem, not the per-frame computations on them.

I tried switching to other buffer usages (USAGE_DYNAMIC), but the allocation failures still occurred at the same levels.

I made a quick alteration to buffer sizes (the buffers that need padding) and am now up to at least 20 million vertices. My GPU is pretty old so that's not bad, though some renderers can go well beyond this, I'm aware.

Going to focus on workarounds and reducing detail where and when possible. I think I can get ~15x more detail with tesselation, so not in bad shape.

If anyone has any more insight, may switch yours to correct answer, but not sure if I'm going to take another path here.